# How can I modify an object without changing its value on database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm manipulating objects from DB. I don't want to change them in the DB, I want to modify them only in the functions scope. Particularly, I'm looking for the user favorites products, so I do:

```
user.products
```

But I wish to remove all favorites products without removing them from the database. I do this:

```
user.products.drop(user.products.count)
```

I need to store it inside `user` temporally. When I do:

```
user.products = user.products.drop(user.products.count)
```

the objects are deleted from database.

Can anyone help me with that? I tested a lot of things and nothing works.

Comment: You say you want to find user's favorite products. How do you have your associations set up between `User` and `Product`? If you have the associations set up correctly, getting favorite products should be trivial. But we can't know since you don't show the relevant code. BTW, the way you're going about seems all wrong to me.

Comment: Sounds to me like you really want to say `user.products.where(...)` to filter the user's products rather that modify what just `user.products` returns.

Comment: Why do you need to do `user.products = ...` with a subset of `user.products`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit the question and add these informations. I didn't think that was relevant, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a duplicate from your original `user` record. It will preserve attributes that are directly on the `user`, but the duplicate will come into existence without any child records.

```
>> duplicate_user = user.dup
>> duplicate_user.products
#> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

So long as you aren't making changes to `duplicate_user` and expecting them to be made to `user`, this should work for you.

If you need to make changes to `duplicate_user` that are eventually saved back to the database, you'll need to apply the changes back to `user` separately.